# Rstudio run command console does not display the result, but the same operation in R gui shows the result

Tags: r

After the command is run in Rstudio, the console has no result output, but after the same command is run in Rgui, there is output in the Rgui console. How to make the Rstudio console display the running result, my Rstudio version is 1.1.456,thanks.

[no output in Rstudio console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84rdN.png)
[expected output in R console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsfsC.png)

Comment: Impossible to tell without input. If I were to take a guess, however, I'd look and see whether, for example, things that are supposed to be printed are actually explicitly printed (as opposed to just passed to the interpreter)

Comment: Please make something *reproducible*. This may include sample code, sample data (e.g., `dput(head(x))`), and how the output differs. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.